# When im making a linq to Sql with an include of an inherited class the sql generate "where in" statement

Tags: ef-core-3.0

If i make this:

C# Code:

```
ModelClass1.Include(r => r.ModelClass2Parent)
```

having ModelClass2Parent three childrens clas i get the following sql code:

```
SELECT ....
FROM [ModelClass1] AS [r]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ...
    FROM [ModelClass2Parent] AS [r0]
    WHERE [r0].[TypeId] IN (1, 3, 2)
) AS [t] ON [r].[Id] = [t].[ModelClass1Id]
ORDER BY [r].[Id], [t].[Id]
GO
```

There is any way to avoid the in clause? 
Its unnecesary and also cause the subquery and bad performance

im expecting something like

SELECT .... FROM [ModelClass1] AS [r] LEFT JOIN [ModelClass2Parent] .... and not with a subquery

Comment: With this amount of information: no. But it's your own responsibility to have proper indexing in the database.

Comment: Whats indexing has to be with this? The point is that the expected sql generated should be something like SELECT ....
FROM [ModelClass1] AS [r]
LEFT JOIN [ModelClass2Parent] ... and not a subquery